# undesired output of the Palindrome program using C++

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

So I started learning C++ two weeks ago and I want to build a program that checks if a string is a palindrome or not.
I tried different ways including the str1==str2 method in the following way:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string empty;
string word;
bool inverse(string word)
{

    for (int i=0;i<=word.length();i++)
    {
         empty+=word[word.length()-i];
    }
    return empty==word;
}

int main()
{ 

    cout<<inverse("civic");

}
```

The output is always 0

Second way: the str1.compare(str2) method

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string empty;
string word;
bool inverse(string word)
{

for (int i=0;i<=word.length();i++)
{empty+=word[word.length()-i];}

if (word.compare(empty))
return true;
else
return false;


}

int main()
{ 

if (inverse(word)==true)
cout<<"is a palindrome";
else
cout<<"is not a palindrome";
cout<<inverse("ano");
cout<<inverse("madam");
}
```

the output is always: is palindrome1 (with 1 or two ones at the end of "palindrome") 
even if the string is not a palindrome.

please explain to me what mistakes I made and how I can correct them.
Also If I want to make my program handle a string that has white space in it, how can I do it?

Comment: `empty+=word[word.length()-i];` will invoke *Undefined behavior* when `i` is zero...

Comment: Your for loop is checking i <= word.length(), while it should check i < word.length()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems

1. Your code is looping too many times. For example a word of three letters should loop three times, but your code loops for 4 (`i=0`, `i=1`, `i=2`, and `i=3`). To fix this you need to change the final condition to use `<` instead of `<=`.
2. You are computing the symmetrical index with the wrong formula. If for example you have a word of length three the letters be `word[0]`, `word[1]` and `word[2]`. However your code uses `length - i` and for `i=0` this will use `word[3]` that is outside the allowed limits for the word. You need to do the indexing using as formula `length - 1 - i` instead of `length - i`.

Both of these errors are quite common in programming and they're called "off-by-one" errors. Remember to always double-check the boundary conditions when you write code so that you can keep this kind of error away from your programs.

Comment: oh I understand, I will make sure to check for the boundaries thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For first one you need to change

```
for (int i=0;i<=word.length();i++)
{empty+=word[word.length()-i];}
```

to this

```
for (int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
{empty+=word[word.length()-(i+1)];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program's behavior will become undefined after this line:

```
for (int i = 0;i <= word.length(); i++)
    empty += word[word.length() - i];
```

Since *length* is always *one plus the last element* (Since the first index is **zero**), when `i` is `0`, then: `word[word.length()]` will give you the element *after* the last element, which is not possible and thus your program will invoke undefined behavior since C/C++... `word[word.length()]` is also possible when `i` itself becomes `word.length()`, so change `<=` (less than or equal to) to `<` (less than)

So, it should be:

```
for (int i = 0;i < word.length(); i++)
    empty += word[word.length() - 1 - i];
```